# ¿Cómo agregar el storage Federated en MySQL?

Tags: mysql

Estoy intentando insertar una tabla federada en mi base de datos local de la siguiente manera:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `NombreTabla` (
`idTabla`,
`campoTabla`) 
ENGINE=FEDERATED DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
CONNECTION='mysql://user:password@host:port/bd/tabla';
```

y consigo el siguiente error:

## 1286 - Unknown storage engine 'FEDERATED'

Hice un `show ENGINES` y no veo el FEDERATED
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Consulté y encontré que debía poner la instrucción federated en el grupo `[mysqld]`, lo hice, inicié de nuevo el mysql y consigo el siguiente error:

```
2016-10-27  9:58:59 19312 [Note] Plugin 'FEEDBACK' is disabled.
2016-10-27  9:58:59 19312 [ERROR] c:\xampp\mysql\bin\mysqld.exe: unknown option '--federated'
2016-10-27  9:58:59 19312 [ERROR] Aborting
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Es posible que la versión de MySQL que viene en tu instalación de xampp no posea ese tipo de almacenamiento. Lo que necesitas es instalar una versión de MySQL que sí lo posea por defecto o instalarlo como plugin tal como se indica [aquí](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/9139) (adaptado):

> Existe un plugin disponible en
>
> ```
> /usr/lib/mysql/plugin/ha_federated.so
> ```
>
> Accedí a la consola de MySQL como root y ejecuté el siguiente query:
>
> ```
> mysql>install plugin federated soname 'ha_federated.so';
> ```
>
> Luego agregué `federated` en mi archivo my.cnf [(my.ini para Windows)] y reinicié el servicio de MySQL.

Para la última parte de agregar `federated` en el archivo de configuración principal de MySQL, solo abres el archivo en un editor de texto y lo agregas en una línea. Aquí un ejemplo:

```
[mysqld]
datadir=/var/lib/mysql #quizás tengas otra ruta
socket=/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock #quizás tengas otra ruta
user=mysql
# Disabling symbolic-links is recommended to prevent assorted security risks
symbolic-links=0
federated #agregamos federated, no requiere nada más
```