# Es posible que una stored procedure funcione con dos bases de datos?

Tags: mysql, base-de-datos, stored-procedure

He estado buscando pero no he encontrado exactamente lo que busco.

Tengo dos bases de datos, llamemosles `Base1` y `base 2` y una stored procedure que se ejecuta en `base 1`, esta base, tiene una serie de tablas espejo que miran a `base 2`. son copias e información redundante.

`base 1`está en pongamos que ip `10.1.1.1`  y base dos en ip `10.2.2.2`.

Lo que quiero es que mi stored procedure haga algo así:

```
BEGIN
DECLARE valor int Default 0;

Select count(*) into valor
From base2.tabla

Insert into base1.tabla
values(valor)

END
```

Por poner un ejemplo.

En [éste enlace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4014780/can-a-stored-procedure-work-with-two-different-databases-how-about-two-servers) pone algo como esto

Me pregunto si podría hacer algo tipo

```
FROM  ip:3306.base2.tabla
```

Algo que me permitiera obtener datos de `base 1`y meterlos en `base 2` para eliminar esa redundancia de datos.

Comment: Me puse a investigar, ya que recordaba haber hecho eso que mencionas en uno de mis trabajos... pero al final, terminé por recordar que lo que hicimos fue realmente [Replicación](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/replication.html) entre distintos servidores (master y slaves)... Aún así sigo pensando que si los SP los ejecutamos basados en los privilegios de usuarios definidos como `user@host`, si tenemos los permisos correctos, tal vez se pueda invocar un SP de otro server, ya que ese server sabe que este usuario tiene permisos, etc....... es una teoría.

Comment: Buf... me parece muy complicado eso, no creo que sea algo sencillo por que la BBDD otra no está situada en mi misma empresa

Comment: Lo sé :( De hecho, me encontré con varias personas preguntando lo mismo que tú, tanto en inglés como español, y en la mayoría o no tenían respuesta, o las que le daban eran del tipo "se ve difícil, no creo que se pueda" ú_ù Pero yo tengo fe XD A ver si los expertos DBA de SOes nos iluminan :D

Comment: Pues ojalá.....

Comment: Yo hace no mucho realicé un script para pasar datos de una base de datos a otra, supongo que es similar pero en un stored procedure. La desventaja es que efectivamente necesita estar en el mismo servidor la BD. (E incluso lo que hice fue de un mismo tipo de BD)

Comment: Por si sirve de algo, en Oracle podemos crear las llamadas "vistas materializadas" que te permite cargar una tabla "temporal" con datos de otra base de datos y que se actualiza dinámicamente cada vez que se realiza un cambio en la tabla original. Algo así te podría servir, solo que tendrías que buscar si mysql permite crear vistas materializadas o su relativo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Según la documentación oficial, una forma que podría responder a tu pregunta es el uso [FEDERATED storage engine](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/federated-storage-engine.html):

> The FEDERATED storage engine lets you access data from a remote MySQL
>   database without using replication or cluster technology. Querying a
>   local FEDERATED table automatically pulls the data from the remote
>   (federated) tables. No data is stored on the local tables.

Es decir:

> El motor de almacenamiento FEDERATED le permite acceder a los datos
>   desde una base de datos MySQL remota sin necesidad de utilizar
>   tecnología de replicación o clúster. La consulta de una tabla local
>   FEDERATED extrae automáticamente los datos de las tablas remotas
>   (federadas). No se almacena ningún dato en las tablas locales.

#### Cómo utilizarlo?

1. En primer lugar, esta funcionalidad no está habilitada por defecto, para hacerlo hay que iniciar el servidor con el parámetro `--federated`. Podemos verificar si disponemos del "engine" haciendo: `show variables like '%federated%';`.
2. Supongamos ahora que en nuestro servidor remoto tenemos la siguiente tabla:

   ```
   CREATE TABLE mitabla (
       id     INT(15) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
       Texto  VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL
       PRIMARY KEY  (id)
   )
   ENGINE=MyISAM
   DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
   ```

   Es un ejemplo, el diseño obviamente puede ser cualquier otro. En nuestro servidor crearemos una tabla "federada" idéntica en estructura a la anterior

   ```
   CREATE TABLE base1_mitabla (
       id     INT(15) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
       Texto  VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL
       PRIMARY KEY  (id)
   )
   ENGINE=FEDERATED
   DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
   CONNECTION='mysql://username:password@hostname:port/database/tablename';
   ```

   Obviamente reemplazar los valores de `CONNECTION` por los que correspondan en tu caso.
3. Si todo marcho como esperábamos, ya tenemos disponible en nuestro database actual una tabla `base1_mitabla` que podremos usar como si la misma fuera local, incluso como parte de un `JOIN`. Deberías repetir el proceso con cualquier otra tabla remota, por ejemplo `base2_mitabla` (tal vez el nombre de la tabla deba contener el nombre del host también)

#### Algunas consideraciones importantes

- Cualquier optimización por existencia de índices se hace en el servidor remoto, lo que es bueno, porque entonces no "viajan" todas las filas de la tabla entre servidores, sin embargo, si el `SELECT` requiere un `TABLE SCAN`, esto significará que el servidor remoto enviará la tabla completa al local.
- El servidor remoto debe ser un MySQL
- La tabla remota debe existir antes de crear la "federada"
- Este modelo no soporta transacciones

Enlaces relacionados:

- [¿Cómo agregar el storage Federated en MySQL?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/30252/31764)
- [Join table from other database and sometimes other server](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11686347/6836377)
- [FEDERATED Storage Engine Notes and Tips](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/federated-usagenotes.html)

Comment: Entiendo los métodos, más o menos, aún así, creo que es demasiado complicado para que mi jefe acepte implementarlo cuando puede seguir haciéndolo de la misma forma habitual. Te doy el positivo por que la respuesta es realmente completa y útil, he conseguido hacer lo que tu me has dicho recreando esta posibilidad en mi casa, aunque he necesitado algo más de documentación. Muchas gracias.